# Jquery toggle close and disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery to toggle multiple targets. I created a piece of code to close the div once it is open. I then close the open div by pressing an x. When I reopen the same toggle the x is not there anymore.

HTML

```
<a class="showSingle" target="1">show 1</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2">show 2</a>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum1 <div class="close">x</div></div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
```

CSS

```
.targetDiv {
    display: none
}
.bio {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

The jquery being used

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index).slideDown();
        jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
  $(".close").click(function(){
      $(".targetDiv").hide("fast");
      $(this).toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

How can I either toggle close by clicking on the bio class or toggle close with the x and have it still re-appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/eLy4b00n/

Comment: `$(this).toggle("fast");` why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know near nothing about JS, but fiddling around with it I got it to work:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index).slideDown();
        $(".close").show("fast");
        jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
  $(".close").click(function(){
      $(".targetDiv").hide("fast");
      $(this).toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Added the following line:

```
$(".close").show("fast");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36b99b8t/